# Too many hit in the application slows the performance down due to excessive RAM usage by SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an overall system performance related quetion:
The architecture of our application is as follows:

Client end => AngularJs app with service calls to get/post data - this client app is hosted in a windows application server through IIS.

We have 3 web api 2 application hosted in the same application server on IIS, Data layer is mostly Entity Framework based call. These APIs are called by the client app through AngularJs $https calls.

We have a separate database server with SQL Server 2014.
Server configuration is as follows:

Database Server => RAM 512 GB, Processor - 56 Core processor

Application Server => RAM 256 GB, Processor - 56 Core processor

IIS has 10 worker process.

Now the problem is:

When too many hit is happening in the application (approx. 1000 hits within 10 mins), the SQL server consumes almost 95% of the RAM and the applications becomes too much slow.
I know SQL server after consuming memory it doesn't free it until new requests arrive. Therefore, probably RAM consumption is not an issue. Once the application becomes slow it 
remains same until we restart the SQL Server Service in the database server.

Please note that at this stage, application server processor usage is average 20%, RAM usage is average 15%.
Database server processor usage is average 25% and RAM usage is 95% as described earlier.

Is there any work around to boost up the performance? Is there any architectural fault here. Please help.

Comment: Why not limit the amout of RAM SQL Server uses? If you haven't limited it, why are you surprised it's using as much as it can?

Comment: I have limited it to 90% and tested. But the result is same. It still slows the application down and affects the overall performance. I am not sure whether Memory consumption is the actual cause or not?

Comment: SQL Server is designed to use as much memory as it can and release it only if it detects host memory pressure due to other applications. 95 percent will leave about 25GB available for use by the OS and other processes so that looks to be normal and expected behavior. What exactly do "hits" mean in your question? I would focus on the number of active connections as reported by [`sp_whoisactive`](http://whoisactive.com/). I suspect thread waits, which might be solved by query/index tuning.

Comment: Hit means number of users actively using the application. Please note that the database is quite large (~3TB) and most of the large tables have indexes and partitions.

Comment: Start with a low value (e.g. 50%) for the DB RAM limit and increase it if necessary. 90% is way too high and you might already be in the bottleneck as @DanGuzman stated. But I assume there is a deeper problem going on: 1000 users per 10 minutes related to your server hardware shouldn't be that problem. But of course this depends on your application. I would start with SQL Server Profiler and watch how many connections your applications are using, how many round-trips are made, how slow and time-consuming your queries are, etc. You should also check views like sys.dm_db_missing_index_details